# Confuse about using javascript setInterval to do animate job

Tags: javascript, jquery-animate, setinterval

I try to use `setInterval` to achieve animate effect in javascript, I want a `div`'s width increase `200px`(the box's origin width is `100px`) in `1000ms`:

```
var MAX = 300, duration = 1000;
var inc = parseFloat( MAX / duration );

var div = $('div')[0];
var width = parseInt(div.style.width, 10);

function animate (id) {
    width += inc;
    if (width >= MAX) {
        clearInterval(id);
        console.timeEnd("animate");
    }
    div.style.width = width + "px";
}

console.time("animate");
var timer = setInterval(function () {
    animate(timer);
}, 0)
```

and I use the `console.time` to calculate how much time it take, however, it always take 3 second and more, not 1 second.

So what's wrong with my code?

the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/nVgTj/2/) is here

but when I use jquery animate, it just as the same time as I pointed:

```
console.time("animate");
$('div').animate({
    width: '300px'
}, { 
    duration: 1000,
    complete: function () {
        console.timeEnd("animate");
    }
})
```

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/cyM9c/2/)

So why jquery could achieve it?What's the secret?

Comment: I personnaly have like 1100~1200ms with plain Javascript and ~1000ms with jQuery...

Answer (score 1):

The "secret" is to calculate the steps you need to take per frame.

Here is an updated example (with some optimizations):
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/nVgTj/7/

```
//init some values
var div = $('div')[0].style;
var height = parseInt(div.height, 10);
var seconds = 1;

//calc distance we need to move per frame over a time
var max = 300;
var steps = (max- height) / seconds / 16.7;

//16.7ms is approx one frame (1000/60)

//loop
function animate (id) {
    height += steps; //use calculated steps
    div.height = height + "px";

    if (height < max) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }
}

animate();
```

Note that as hh54188 points out, `requestAnimationFrame` is not available in all browsers yet (Chrome and Firefox supports it with prefixes).

You can use this polyfill which allow you to use the call no matter, but fall backs gracefully to `setTimeout` if `requestAnimationFrame` shouldn't be available.

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: I didn't add ease-out as in the jQuery, but I have this example for how to do that: http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/UMqD2/  My formula *may* be a bit off here (it's 5am) but you see the concept.

Comment: I don't quite understand `var steps = (max - height) / 16.7 / (seconds + 1);` especially why need `seconds` plus 1

Comment: @hh54188 as said, it was 5 in the morning. Updated with the correct one now that the head is a bit more clear. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The solution @Ken said is an available one, but the browser don't support `requestAnimationFrame`, it could't work;

The mistake I made in my code is, what I calculate the increasement is increased per 1ms, but the timer execute my animate function per 4ms (according to the minimum delay).

So for some insurance，we better set the timer delay by hand, like `13ms` (the interval in jquery animation), and the increasement should be:

```
var inc = parseFloat( MAX / duration ) * 13;
```

use the `13 * perOneMillisecond` as the increasement for matching the `13ms` interval

Here is the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hh54188/nVgTj/6/), then you can check time cost almost as the jquery(but still slower some, why?)

Comment: Just use this polyfill which fallbacks to setTimeout if requestAnimationFrame is not available: http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Comment: The minimum delay you can have (if you want screen refresh) is 1000/60 ms (about 16.7ms, but setTimeout/setInterval can only take an integer value and doesn't sync to vblank so you will eventually get jerks in the animation).